# What is Symfony and its use in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I want to what is Symfony, that what is the purpose of it and also
wanna know whether Laravel makes use of it or not? If makes use of it
then for what?

**Regarding this, I searched and found that:**

> Symfony is a set of reusable PHP components, enabling the developer to
> create scalable, high-performance applications. ... Many popular
> projects, including Drupal and phpBB, also use a Symfony framework. In
> fact, Laravel, the most popular PHP framework, is build off of
> Symfony.

Here it is mentioned that Laravel s build off of Symfony, If Laravel
makes no use of Symfony then why in somewhere in some error we found some errors where Symfony is mentioned?

**e.g**

```
symfony\component\debug\exception\fatalerrorexception: allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in /var/www/html/api/v2/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/functions.php:125 stack trace:
```

This is Laravel produced error, and you can see here  Symfony is mentioned in it. Is there anything I'm not understanding?

I hope experts will help me, Thank you.

Comment: Error simply tells that PHP needs 64 MB memory (RAM) but can't allocate. (Memory may be limited by php.ini or something else).

Comment: you can increase memory  with ```ini_set```  function

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you have to understand how those frameworks are made.

a framework is a set of packages that are integrated in the project that give you the ability to do things in a more simple way.

Laravel didn't invent everything, there is a lot of packages inside laravel that don't belong to laravel but to Symfony for example.

Take a look at composer, packages management... you will understand more.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the limit for:

`max_input_time`
`memory_limit` 
`max_execution_time`

These parameters are configured in the `php.ini` file. 
You can find the meanings of these directives [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

I recommend using a maximum of 128MB for the PHP `memory_limit` limit, or even less. If the script requires more than 128MB of memory, then in most cases revision and optimization of the script code are required.